# Конкатенация и оператор «,»

Tags: php

Я заметил, что делать конкатенацию можно как и точкой, так и запятой. Но в чем разница между этими двумя операторами?

Comment: Пример на ideone можно?

Comment: @Erepaha, просто прочитайте это http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php Там объяснение на русском языке.

Comment: Как только Вы попробуете "конкатенацию запятой" где-то ещё, кроме `echo` - сразу поймёте разницу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никакой конкатенации через запятую в php нет. То, что вы приняли за оную по ссылке php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php на русскоязычную документацию, на самом деле результат трудностей перевода. Во-первых, обратите внимание, как показан пример использования данной функции:

```
void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )
```

Тут ясно видно, что запятая выступает в роли разделителя аргументов.

Во-вторых, ниже в [оригинале](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) написано вот что:

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are **not required to use parentheses with it**. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, **if you want
>   to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be
>   enclosed within parentheses**.

А в переводе вот что:

> На самом деле echo - это не функция, а конструкция языка, поэтому
>   **заключать аргументы в скобки необязательно**. echo (в отличие от других
>   языковых конструкций) не ведет себя как функция, поэтому не всегда
>   может быть использована в контексте функции. Вдобавок, **если вы хотите
>   передать более одного аргумента в echo, эти аргументы нельзя заключать
>   в скобки**.

На мой взгляд, в оригинале более ясно, что скобки могут использоваться только в том случае, если в `echo` передается один аргумент, а в остальных случаях аргументы передаются без скобок через запятую, которая будет являться тут разделителем этих аргументов, а не оператором конкатенации.

В итоге, вы можете попробовать вывести с помощью этой функции несколько переменных разного типа данных и сравнить увиденное с результатом вывода с использованием конкатенации.

```
echo "test " . true . 1;
echo "test " , true , 1;
```